# error creating daily logs in rails app on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, logging, heroku, rake-task

I have a rails 5 app that I'd like to push to heroku, in which I have a logger that creates a daily log file, which I use to print out various pieces of status information. This works in development, but I get an error when I try to push it to heroku (after pushing everything to git).

The error I receive: "Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /tmp/build_e3fe50d2e37e0a51f1bc7d94dd1fc2f3/log/daily_logs_production/2016-12-19.log
"

Here is the relevant portion from production.rb:

```
if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/daily_logs_production/#{Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}.log", 'daily')
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end
```

Any idea what is wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whether or not you are getting an error can be neglected.

due to the [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) of heroku dynos you should not use it for such purposes.

install a [plugin of the Logging category](https://elements.heroku.com/addons) instead.